# create form that will take user to different page

Tags: javascript

This sounds like such a simple thing to do, but I am having lots of trouble figuring it out. I don't have much knowledge in making form so that doesn't help either.  Following is what I would like to happen.

I would like to create an input text field on a form where a user from a company enters there company name. They would then click submit.  Based on the company name a web page would open that was designed for that company.

I only have about 5 companies and 5 different web pages so this is not real big.

I also need something where if they enter the wrong company name it lets the user know and give the choice to exit the form or try again.

Hopefully someone can help me do this as easy as possible.

Comment: You can't start from zero and ask for 100% of the code. Show some work and describe where you are stuck.

Comment: @Diodeus Nor can you tell someone not to do what they haven't done... (hopefully someone can *help* me do this != can I have the required code) Your second sentence mandates that I move away from the flag-comment icon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic page to get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/uaAXz/1/

You are going to need to add in some more logic for determining what webapge you are going to redirect to and to see if its a valid company or not. Ill leave that up to you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#goButton").click(function() {

        var companyName = $("#companyName").val();

        // do stuff with the company name (see if it valid)

        alert("GO TO THE WEB PAGE FOR:" +  companyName );

        // go somewhere based off of the name
        //document.location = "http:\\www.google.ca"
    });

});
```

(Remember to warp that up in a script element)

And then for your html, all you need to get started is:

```
<input type="textfield" id="companyName" />
<br/>
<input type="button" id="goButton" value="GO" />
```

Hope this gets you on your way :)

Answer (score 0):

This is much harder than what I thought.  Here is what I have, do you think it will work?.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#goButton").click(function() {

    var companyName = $("#companyName").val();

    // do stuff with the company name (see if it valid)

    alert("GO TO THE WEB PAGE FOR:" +  companyName );

    if (companyName = compa)
```

//document.location = "www.compa.html"

```
    if (companyName = compb)
```

//document.location = "www.compb.html"

```
    else
```

//document.location = "www.comp.html"

```
    // go somewhere based off of the name
    //document.location = "http:\\www.google.ca"
});
```

});

I am not sure what you meant by "wrap that up in a script element".  Did I do that above`.

I am not having a problem with the htlm file. I have that down pat.